# How to modify a 3S Li-ion BMS for a string of only 2 cells in series?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, bms

Could you please help me to find a trick for protecting just 2 lithium-ion 18650 cells in series with a 3S BMS?

This is an image of this BMS:
[image: BMS and 3 cells]

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: the circuit relies on the presence of 3 individual cells in series and the power supply voltage of provided by 3 cells when they are empty. Two cells do not provide enough voltage to the IC when empty. The IC shuts down the battery current if any cell voltage is 0 V, so you can't skip any cell.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the two resistors below the 12.6V label, short 8.4V to the 12.6V pad.
The batteries should be connected as labelled.